# Django 1.6 and python 3.3 database name setup

Tags: django, python-3.x, web-frameworks

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

How can I change the name of the database properly ?

Comment: SQLite is file-based. A database has no name, only a file path.

Comment: yes but I mean to give the database a name such as myproject.sqlite3

Comment: this is correct. what's the problem? Unless there's something special about P3 / S3